# get xml attribute in jquery for image parsing

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

basically I am pulling the options of the select drop down from this xml snippet, I need to load these images in a div onclick of an option in the dropdown. How do I parse this image  attribute.

```
<menu>
    <optionheading>
        <heads>Heading 1</heads>
                    <value>
                            <values image='images/img1.gif'>Option1</values>
                            <values image='images/img2.gif'>Option2</values>
                            <values image='images/img3.gif'>Option3</values>
                    </value>
    </optionheading>

</menu>
```

Anybody got any Ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the image attibute use [jQUery paserXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) which will allow you to navigate the DOM.

example -

```
var xml = "<menu><optionheading><heads>Heading 1</heads><value><values image='images/img1.gif'>Option1</values><values image='images/img2.gif'>Option2</values><values image='images/img3.gif'>Option3</values></value></optionheading></menu>";

xmlDoc = jQuery.parseXML(xml);
$xml = $( xmlDoc );
alert($xml.find('values:contains("Option1")').attr('image'));
$xml.find('values').each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('image'));
})
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/XmJrN/8/

Comment: Isn't this running only for one image, My xml has actually 90 images and they need to be populated in a div
http://jsfiddle.net/XmJrN/7/

Comment: Thank you @Jayendra for the spark. This helped me to track down an image located in a feed. I used something similar to this, in search of an image that was inside of a description element in the xml document - $(this).find('description:contains("image")').text();